# Why do they use only the output values to plot the points?

Tags: calculus, functions, vector-spaces

I know that a vector-valued function produces two values from one.
Consider f(x)=(2x,5x)

Why do they use only the output values to plot the points, whereas at a normal function we use the input as well as the output to plot the points?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a man on a unicycle, going around in a circle in the snow.

For each fixed value to $t$, say $t=t_0$, the man is at the point $(x,y)=(\cos t_0,\sin t_0)$.

If we let $t$ change from $0$ to $2\pi$ then $(\cos t, \sin t)$ traces out a circle in the snow.

The tracks that the man leaves in the snow tell us exactly where he has been. That is all we are really interested in. The man's wheel touched the two-dimensional earth and we want to know where he went. The output values that you mention is the circle in the snow made by his unicycle.

You might also be interested to know both *when* and *where*. In that case, you *could* plot $(x,y,t)$ given by $(\cos t, \sin t, t)$ which gives helix. Representing a unicycles path by a spiral in three dimensions seems a little unnatural.

Comment: And cannot we achieve this with regular functions?

Comment: I can also imagine some parabola function producing half of that circle, something like this f:(a,b)->R f(x)=x^2 and then you could define it using a piecewise function to draw a circle.